# Magento 2 : Update shipping price in checkout summary by default on shipping step when there is only one shipping method available

Tags: magento2

I need to update checkout summary with shipping price by default when only one shipping method is available on shipping step.
Currently shipping price is updated when I move on to payment step.

If someone can help then it will helpful, thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

After some research got the solution to set shipping price to summary on checkout if there is only one shipping method available.

For this, need to extend `"/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js"`

Have to define *'`Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/estimate-service`'* and pass dependency *`estimateService`* into function.

Comment out this line *`var price =  this.totals().shipping_amount;`* under function *`getValue: function()`* and add following two lines after that.

```
var shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();
var price =  shippingMethod.amount;
```

I am adding screen shot of entire file ***/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js*** how it looks after extending and editing.

[image]

Comment: if have 2  shipping method, how to fix it? thank you @SachinBhave

Comment: this should be accepted as the answer. I had the same problem and this saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

Updated solution (M240)

> requirejs-config.js

```
    config: {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> Vendor_Module/js/view/summary/shipping-mixin

```
define([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default'
], function (quote, totalsDefaultProvider) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        initialize: function () {
            quote.shippingMethod.subscribe(this.estimateTotalsShipping);

            return this._super();
        },

        estimateTotalsShipping: function () {
            totalsDefaultProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
        },

        getValue: function () {
            var price;

            if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                return this.notCalculatedMessage;
            }
            price = quote.shippingMethod().amount;

            return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**After applied these solutions, It will give another issues.**

**Issues:**- B2B customer once they are trying to place negotiated Quote on checkout page then it's redirecting to customer account page.

Can you please provide the solutions for that?