# Magento 2: Checkout page Summary Sidebar not update the total

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.3

Currently, Checkout page Summary Sidebar not update the total
how can i fix it?
please help

Comment: Please check on console any js error.

Comment: for exsample: AU shipping is $10, US is $20, but i change the US the shipping still showing $10.@Vijay-CyberLocker

Comment: Let me show your site. Is there shipping method not change right.

Comment: my problem look like this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/216217/magento-2-update-shipping-price-in-checkout-summary-by-default-on-shipping-ste , but i have 2~3 shipping method. and his code only fix shipping total, but grand total and subtotal are not update. @Vijay-CyberLocker